# Batch file to Copy current datewise folder by skipping a Parent folder and using Robocopy to monitor and copy source after changes

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I have been using Robocopy to backup files and now i need to do something like this

"robocopy [D:\test1\21-09-2013\sample.txt] [destination]"

here i have a lot of folders as Test1,test2,...testn. and beneath every test folders there are date wise folder.

So i got the below answer to copy current dated folder by skipping its parent directory.

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "mydate=%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%"
for /d %%a in (D:\test*) do 
(
    if exist "%%~a\%mydate%\" 
    (
     robocopy %%~a\%mydate% E:\backup\%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%\ /xo /LOG+:file /TEE /NP /mon:2
    )
)
```

It works fine without that monitor and if i use monitor, it stops with the first parent directory i.e test1 and waits for 2 changes.

What i exactly want is, It should copy the available(current dated) folders from all parent directory(test1,test2,..testn) and then it should monitor and run again with the changes. Also I couldn't run this if i scheduled this in Windows task scheduler. Requesting further help....

Comment: Can you run the batch file (without monitoring) every say 5 minutes and it will update any changes then?  A loop is easy to include in the batch file.

Comment: Yes i am able to run every 15 minutes (since the job is ending within 13-15 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Here the code is essentially the same as in your question, with the addition of a `timeout` command (vista and higher) that waits for 900 seconds/15 minutes and then runs the batch file again by branching to the `:loop` label.

```
@echo off
setlocal
:loop
set "mydate=%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%"
for /d %%a in (D:\test*) do (
    if exist "%%~a\%mydate%\" (
         robocopy "%%~a\%mydate%" "E:\backup\%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%" /xo /LOG+:file /TEE /NP
    )
)
timeout 900
goto :loop
```